Develop Spring 3.x SOAP consummer service with vscode
We just try to upgrade the project from Spring 2.x to Spring 3.x, and we have to invoke a thrid party SOAP web service in our project.
The existing plugin for SOAP service call seems not work in Spring 3.x.
We follow the guides from Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service, and tested with the producer and consumer sample.
Everything works fine in command line, it can build and execute without issue.
But there are many error reported in vscode, especially in the consumer project.
It seems that it cannot recongize the objects created from remote service in target folder.
The error can be eaily repeated by opening the complete project in https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-consuming-web-service.
(Note, it must have producer project running in order to build the java interface object for the SOAP service.)
vscode cannot reconize the object in generated-sources
In this case, we cannot run the project directly in vscode, and when we try to modify the code for the third party web service, it there has any error reported, it's hard to identify if the error is caused by vscode or our program bug, and we cannot run the debugger also.
In Spring 2.x, we use the maven-jaxb2-plugin, but it has to change to jaxws-maven-plugin for Spring 3.0 according to the guilde.
In fact, there already have some warning message in the pom.xml when open the sample project,
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: com.sun.xml.ws:jaxws-maven-plugin:3.0.0:wsimport (execution: default, phase: generate-sources)
We don't know if this may relate to the issue that vscode cannot recongize the generated-sources in target folder.
Does anyone know how to config vscode to refer to the object in generated-soruces folder?  We guess this should be default setting, but seems not.
Tested in command line, no error reported.  But there are many error reported in vscode.
We hope that vscode can reconize the object in generated-sources, and remove those error.

Just found a solution here https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-java/issues/177 by adding build-helper-maven-plugin, config the source to ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/wsimport/, then vscode can reconize the generated objects.
